# How to send pk in header body of PUT request instead of changing the API end point url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was trying to implement all of CRUD in a single Generic class based API using Django REST Framework. Is there a way I can do this without changing the end point and including `<int:pk>` in it?

My main motive for not including `<int:pk>` in the urls file is that I will not be able to use this url for create if I did that.

**api.py**

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model  # used custom user model
from rest_framework import mixins
from .serializers import UserSerializer

User = get_user_model()


class UserAPI(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path, include, re_path
    from .api import UserAPI

    urlpatterns = [

        path('register/<int:pk>', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user_create'),


    ]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.forms import ValidationError


User = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        extra_kwargs = {'last_name': {'required': True}}

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = User.objects.create(email=validated_data['email'],
                                   first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                   last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                   )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`Modelviewset`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) instead of `GenericAPIView`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class UserAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and change your `urls.py` to

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from .api import UserAPI
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'register', UserAPI)
urlpatterns = [

              ] + router.urls
```

The [DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) class provides all end-point that are required for CRUD operations.

Here is the API reference table:

```
| API end-points        | HTTP Method   | Result                                    |
|---------------------  |-------------  |------------------------------------------ |
| /register             | GET           | List of Users                             |
| /register             | POST          | Create new User                           |
| /register/{user_pk}   | GET           | Retrieve details of particular user       |
| /register/{user_pk}   | PUT           | Fully update particular user's info       |
| /register/{user_pk}   | PATCH         | Partially update particular user's info   |
| /register/{user_pk}   | DELETE        | Delete particular User's details from DB  |
```